# MySql command line unescaped apostrophe

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping, command-prompt

I have created many tables and have been adding data with the insert command.

The latest command I wrote:

```
mysql> insert into review values (1,2,3,5,'Shakespear is totally the world's pre-eminant dramtist! Hes my fav <3',2012-10-15);
```

Unforuntately, I forgot to escape the apostrophe  in "world's", and now my command line is stuck, and I am worried about losing all of the data I've input already.

```
Windows command line just looks like this:
    '>exit;
    '>help;
    '>nothing i type here does anything!!!
```

Please help me get back to

```
mysql> so i can add things in this area
```

or just so I can get to the DOS and do:

```
C:/xampp/mysql/bin> mysqldump -u root -- mydatabase > mydb.sql
```

Please help me save my work!! :)

Answer (score 4):

When it says:

```
'>
```

It means that there's an extra `'` that needs to be closed before completing the statement. Try typing:

```
'> ';
```

That will fail the current statement*, so you can try it again correctly.

* It fails in most cases, since the resulting statement is probably not valid SQL. If it were, then you'd end up with some wonky data...but you'd be able to fix it with some DELETE or UPDATE statements. In your case, `s pre-eminant dramatist! ...` is not valid outside of quotes, so it'll fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just type Ctl-C and you should get back to the shell prompt. You'll lose the command you were in the middle of entering, but you're going to lose that anyway. You don't lose any other data you've input, that's all in the database (unless you started a transaction -- I think Control-C will do a ROLLBACK rather than COMMIT).